# standard select1st and select2nd

Tags: c++, tuples, functor

Is there any standard `select1st` and `select2st` equivalent in `C++11`?
It seems that these has been defined only in [GNU CPP](http://www.aoc.nrao.edu/php/tjuerges/ALMA/STL/html-3.4.6/struct____gnu__cxx_1_1select1st.html).

Comment: There was [`std::bind1st()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind1st/) and [`std::bind2nd()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/bind2nd/) but in C++11 all you need is [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @0x499602D2 and in C++14 there are polymorphic lambdas which is superior in every way. I guess `std::bind` is part of the short-lived "Bronze Age" known as C++11.  We have better tools now ;-)

Answer (score 9):

For all things that `get` is defined on:

```
template <std::size_t N>
constexpr auto select = [] (auto&& x) noexcept -> decltype(auto) {
  return std::get<N>(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x));
};
```

Comment: What does the perfect forwarding version do? `std::forward` is a no-op here: the return type is always `first_type`, no matter whether pair is l-value reference or r-value reference. Possible fix: `auto select1st = ... { return std::get<0>(std::forward<decltype(pair)>(pair)); };`.

Comment: @Evg A slip on my side. Member-access expressions are also differentiated by `decltype`.

Comment: What if you pass `std::pair<T&&, U&&>&&` to it? Shouldn't the return type of `select1st()` be `T&&` and not `T&`?

Comment: @Evg Let's go with `get` since that works on tuples as well